# Firefox absolute positioning issue with rotate transform

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am attempting to make some nice looking, flexible arrow buttons with CSS only by using a rotate. Problem is that Firefox seems to position the arrow part slightly differently to all other browsers. Adding Firefox only styles can of course address this, but is there a more elegant way?

HTML as follows

```
<span class="arrow-box left">Previous button</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<span class="arrow-box right">Next button</span>
```

CSS is as follows

```
.arrow-box { line-height:34px; border:2px solid #7E95AF; padding:8px 20px; z-index:10; font-family:Arial; font-weight:bold; font-size:12px; border-radius:5px; background-color:#EEE; position:relative; }
.arrow-box.left { border-left:0; }
.arrow-box.right { border-right:0; }

.arrow-box.left::before,
.arrow-box.right::after { content:""; display:block; width:24px; height:24px; transform:rotate(45deg); -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg); z-index:-1; position:absolute; border-style:solid; border-color:#7E95AF; border-radius:5px; background-color:#EEE; }
.arrow-box.left::before { top:2px; left:-10px; border-width:0 0 2px 2px; }
.arrow-box.right::after { top:2px; right:-10px; border-width:2px 2px 0 0; }
```

Working version for Chrome, IE, Safari: http://jsfiddle.net/YWnzc/356/

Working version for Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/YWnzc/352/

Comment: For reference, the fiddle including the Firefox only css is here http://jsfiddle.net/YWnzc/358/

Answer (score 0):

Yes your `border-right width` changes when the browser is Firefox, So i think you can use a function in javascript to detect the browser and do changes according to it.

you can do like this...

**Javascript :**

```
var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';   // Firefox 1.0+

if(isFirefox == true)
{
  $('.arrow-box.right').toggleClass('changed');
}
```

**CSS :**

```
.arrow-box.right.changed:after { top:2px; right:-7px; border-width:2px 2px 0 0; }
```

I have called a changed css for `.arrow-box.right` , you can do changes for `.arrow-box.left` also if you want.
Check this fiddle in both Firefox and Chrome-> http://jsfiddle.net/YWnzc/360/

Comment: I'm sure it will work, although as stated in post I'm trying to do this elegantly in CSS only (more of a purist question than how can I do it as my response shows how it can be done). Ideally I'd like to know the root cause and then how it can be worked around using a different technique/style.